# Why multiple process is slower than single when I'm trying to accelerate my program by multiprocess.Pool in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing, threadpool

I know many people asked the similar question. But I can't find any thing can explain the phenomenon. Here is my code.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

def _foo(x):
    np.linalg.inv(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    r = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
    p = Pool(2)
    p.map(_foo, [r.copy() for i in range(8)])
    print 'Finished in', time.time() - t, 'sec'
```

When I use other time-consuming operating to test my code rather than `np.linalg.inv`. It works fine. I do get the performance improvement with increasing size of the `Pool`. However, when I using `np.linalg.inv` in function `_foo`, `Pool(2)` is extremely slower than `Pool(1)`. `Pool(1)` finished in 0.77 and `Pool(2)` is 9.84. The code is tested on a machine which has 6 physics core.

The only explanation I can infer is the `inv` method sharing some resources. But I have copied `r` for every process. It seems no need to do so.

Comment: I run your code with `Pool(1)` and get 0.75 sec, and with `Pool(2)` and get 0.57 sec.  Are you on windows, or are your other cores being used while you run the code?  `multiprocessing` uses some shared memory… but on windows, it has to copy more upon spawning a new process (because windows doesn't have a true fork).  More info would help.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I test my code on ubuntu 15.10. And htop shows all cores are at 100% rate

Comment: I might then suggest you try something like this: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/examples/test_profile.py

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Thank you. I tested it and it works fine. I did some more tests. It seems a bug only occurs on the method using openBLAS. I installed numpy 1.9.0 without openBLAS, this issue does not occur.

Comment: you should answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the point. It is a "bug" of numpy builed with openBLAS on Ubuntu. Since Unbuntu 12.04, openBLAS became multithreading. So when I start two processing to accelerate my computation, there is actually 24 thread running on 6 physical cores. It is a typical overhead problem.

My method to solve it is set environmental variable OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1. This force openBLAS to run in single thread mode.